# Struggling to change dataframe column dtype to datetime from importing CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm struggling to change a dataframe column from an object to a datetime column.

How this is being done is that I'm importing an excel csv file as a dataframe

The dataframe (when importing the CSV) would look like this:

```
df = {'Email': ['test.user@gmail.com'],
        'Forename': ['Test'],
        'Surname': ['User'],
        'Gender': ['MALE'],
        'Postcode': [''],
        'Date of Birth': ['19/03/1976'],
        'Email Opt In': ['TRUE'],
        'Email Opt In Date Captured': ['07/01/2019']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (df)
```

Next I rename the columns within the dataframe so that they match the destination table within the database:

```
tablelist = {
    "opt_in_table": {
        "Email":"email",
        "Forename":"forename",
        "Surname":"surname",
        "Gender":"gender",
        "Postcode":"post_code",
        "Date of Birth":"date_of_birth",
        "Email Opt In":"email_opt_in",
        "Email Opt In Date Captured": "email_opt_in_date_captured"
        }
}

df = df.rename(columns=metadata.tablelist["opt_in_table"])
```

After importing the CSV as a dataframe and changing the column names, I then attempt to change the two columns 'date_of_birth' & 'email_opt_in_date_captured' to datetime using the following code:

```
df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'])
df['email_opt_in_date_captured'] = pd.to_datetime(df['email_opt_in_date_captured'])
```

When trying to change the following columns, I'm met with the following error:

**TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>**

When creating the dataframe from scratch (using the code to construct it) instead of importing the CSV (which is the exact same as the df dataframe code mentioned above), I am able to change the two columns using to_datetime successfully but not when I'm importing the CSV as a dataframe.

Has anyone got more of an idea of why it's not happy with my date columns? I've tried the following so far and nothing seems to be working:

- Adding parameters errors='coerce'/errors='ignore' with format='%m%d%Y' into to_datetime
- Checked the csv for any anomalies (date columns either have a date or nothing there)
- fill.na to replace all null values in the date columns with a default date

Comment: What are the contents of the two date columns when importing from the CSV?  I recommend updating the question with this detail.  Remember, we do not have access to your data, therefore statements like "when creating the dataframe from scratch (with the above code) and changing the column to a datetime, it all works" are unhelpful, as we have nothing to go on.  We can only help solve a problem with data that is provided to us.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've made some changes to help clarify things in the question.

The contents of the two date columns are the same as the code within the df dataframe. The df dataframe mimics the exact output from the CSV file when it is imported as a dataframe so that would serve as provided data.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that when importing the CSV, the following needed to be done so that it would work:

- add **encoding = "ISO-8859-1"** when using pd.read_csv
- add **errors='coerce'** when using pd.to_datetime